# html tables with no padding renders OK in desktop mailers but there is an unwanted additional horizontal padding on webmails

Tags: html, css

I am working on an html email.
I have a problem with 2 images displayed onto a table:

```
        <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td >
                        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="BAKERTILLY vous souhaite ses meilleurs voeux pour 2016 / Bests wishes for 2016 from BAKERTILLY" style="border: none;" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <td  >
            <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Cliquez pour voir l'animation" style="border: none;" />
    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
```

(same results if I had style="padding:0px;" into the td tags.)

It works fine on desktop browsers, but web mailers somehow an horizontal padding between table cells.

Is there a known way to get rid off this unwanted padding?

Comment: Probably this old issue again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image

Comment: display:block;
made the trick, thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `border-collapse` property on the table to solve this issue on mailers.

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
```